# How to close TCP connection when invalid user trying to POST large file?

Tags: c++, nginx, fastcgi

I wrote a simple HTTP responding C++ program using http://www.fastcgi.com library + nginx web-server. It works almost great. But I noticed that fcgi's function

```
int FCGX_Accept_r(FCGX_Request *request);
```

doesnt return before all the request transmitted to the server. The problem: i am unable to analyze parameters from URI before file transmission is finished: i want to analyze "?sid=" argument to reject transmission from invalid user. It would be a waste of bandwidth to allow anyone send 1GB files to a server.

As i know, web-server always send FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST via FastCGI connection when new request started, then FCGI_PARAMS etc. So it would be good to react to content of some parameters before user transmitted all the (possibly unneeded and too large) data.

Also i will read more nginx documentation about its FastCGI abilities.

**update:**
Trying to send 2 GB file to nginx via HTML-form + sniffing the exchange between nginx and fastcgi: nginx doesn't even try to send a byte to FastCGI application before all the 2GB has come. So, this behavior is kinda normal. And if you want the functionality i am asking for, it turns out that you should develop your own nginx's module or simple web-server. Hm...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can control by this :

```
location /xxx/upload {
    access_by_lua '
        //check cookie or something can recognize the req is valid or not
    ';
    fcgi_pass XXXX;
}
```

check this link :
    http://openresty.org/